# Oracle join not working as expected

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running a left outer join on two tables, but the results fetched are not as expected. I have given the examples below :

When I run condition on individual tavles , below are the counts.

```
select count(*) from TableA 
where ColumnA= 'X'
and ColumnB like 'ABC'

--Count 10000

select count(*) from TableB 
where ColumnD in ('hello','there')

--Count 7350

select count(*) from TableA ta
LEFT JOIN TableB tb
on ta.ColumnM = tb.ColumnN
where ta.ColumnA= 'X'
and ta.ColumnB like 'ABC'
and tb.ColumnD in ('hello','there')

Expected Count - 10000
Actual Count - 7300
```

I am assuming my understanding of joins is not correct in this case. can anyone explain the behaviour and let me know where I am going wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are expecting 10k lines returned is a left join should produce a row for everyone that is in the first table.  When it doesn't find a row, it produces a null, which you are dropping with this clause:

```
and tb.ColumnD in ('hello','there')
```

If you want the 10k rows, apply the where clause on table b prior to the jouin, not after:

```
select count(*) from TableA ta
LEFT JOIN (select * from TableB  tb.ColumnD in ('hello','there') ) tb
on ta.ColumnM = tb.ColumnN
where ta.ColumnA= 'X'
and ta.ColumnB like 'ABC'
```

Edit...this works better, thanks for the comment:

```
select count(*) from TableA ta
LEFT JOIN TableB tb
on ta.ColumnM = tb.ColumnN and  tb.ColumnD in ('hello','there')
where ta.ColumnA= 'X'
and ta.ColumnB like 'ABC'
```

Comment: Good explanation but the inline view isn't necessary. `left join tableb tb on  ta.ColumnM = tb.ColumnN and tb.ColumnD in ('hello','there')` will work fine

Answer (score 4):

Your `where` condition on the outer joined table (`tb.ColumnD in ('hello','there')`) turns the outer join back into an inner join.

You need to apply that condition in the join clause:

```
select count(*) 
from TableA ta
  LEFT JOIN TableB tb 
         on ta.ColumnM = tb.ColumnN
        and tb.ColumnD in ('hello','there')
where ta.ColumnA= 'X'
  and ta.ColumnB like 'ABC'
```